# PowerShell Invoke-Command from ASP.net application

Tags: c#, powershell, winrm

I have an asp .net webservice in c#, which execute powershell scripts in remote host, through invoke-command tools (winrm).
If I execute the invoke-command from powershell directly, this works fine.

```
Invoke-Command -ConnectionURI http://localhost:5985 -ScriptBlock {new-item c:\\dir1 -itemtype directory} -Credential $mycreds
```

Where $mycreds is set as username and password

But when I try to execute the same from c#

```
String cmd = "$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -AsPlainText -force; 
              $mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('Administrador', $secpasswd);
              Invoke-Command -ConnectionURI http://localhost:5985 -ScriptBlock {new-item c:\\dir1 -itemtype directory} -Credential $mycreds";

 Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
 runspace.Open();
 Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
 pipeline.Commands.AddScript(cmd);
 Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
 return (results.Count).ToString();
```

The count return 0, but if I change the script for this:

```
   String cmd = "$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -AsPlainText -force; 
echo $secpasswd";
```

The count return 1, and print: "System.Security.SecureString". Then I am sure that the c# script it's ok, but I have a some kind of rights issue in PowerShell.

My winrm configuration is:

```
> PS C:\Users\Administrador> winrm get winrm/config Config
>     MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 150
>     MaxTimeoutms = 60000
>     MaxBatchItems = 32000
>     MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
>     Client
>         NetworkDelayms = 5000
>         URLPrefix = wsman
>         AllowUnencrypted = false
>         Auth
>             Basic = true
>             Digest = true
>             Kerberos = true
>             Negotiate = true
>             Certificate = true
>             CredSSP = false
>         DefaultPorts
>             HTTP = 5985
>             HTTPS = 5986
>         TrustedHosts = *
>     Service
>         RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GWGX;;;WD)
>         MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
>         MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 15
>         EnumerationTimeoutms = 60000
>         MaxConnections = 25
>         MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
>         AllowUnencrypted = false
>         Auth
>             Basic = false
>             Kerberos = true
>             Negotiate = true
>             Certificate = false
>             CredSSP = false
>             CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
>         DefaultPorts
>             HTTP = 5985
>             HTTPS = 5986
>         IPv4Filter = *
>         IPv6Filter = *
>         EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
>         EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
>         CertificateThumbprint
>     Winrs
>         AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
>         IdleTimeout = 180000
>         MaxConcurrentUsers = 5
>         MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
>         MaxProcessesPerShell = 15
>         MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 150
>         MaxShellsPerUser = 5
```

I also run:

```
Enable-PsRemoting -Force
```

I set

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

In my Session_Configuration I get:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrador>  Get-PSSessionConfiguration | Format-List -Property Name, Permission


Name       : microsoft.powershell
Permission : BUILTIN\Administradores AccessAllowed

Name       : Microsoft.PowerShell32
Permission :

Name       : microsoft.ServerManager
Permission : BUILTIN\Administradores AccessAllowed
```

Where microsoft.ServerManager is IIS, I guess.

My winrm version:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrador> winrm id
IdentifyResponse
    ProtocolVersion = http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd
    ProductVendor = Microsoft Corporation
    ProductVersion = OS: 6.1.7601 SP: 1.0 Stack: 2.0
```

And PowerShell version:

PS C:\Users\Administrador> Get-Host

Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 2.0
InstanceId       : 5eb97936-a0a4-450d-b2cc-57069d1ea7e6
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : es-CO
CurrentUICulture : es-ES
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

Answer (score 0):

I went to Task Manager, Process tab and look by w3wp.exe and the User that was executing that process was "DefaultAppPool", I guess that this user have not rights to remote access or execution on PowerShell. (Image shows Administrador because I already change it)
[image]

To change the user go to IIS Manager, in application groups, my site's application groups shows in Identity: ApplicationPoolIdentity, Select the application pool and click Advanced Settings, in Process Model, select Identity and click the ellipsis (the button with the three dots). In Personal Account sets an Administrator account with username and password, reboot IIS.

[image]

If I look by Task Manager, iis user has changed